# How to add an entry to File Menu bar in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, add-in, ieaddon

Is there a way to customize File Menu in internet explorer. I am making an add-in in which i want to add something next to File->Send or say File->Print.

by documentations, i saw that only Help Menu and Toolbars can be customized in IE. However i have some add-ins which add entries in File mennu...